# ¿Cómo invocar una accion de Logout desde ajax en asp net core mvc?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp, asp.net-core-mvc

Espero me puedan ayudar con este problema que tengo, necesito saber como puedo llamar desde Ajax a la acción de deslogeo que tengo en un controlador.
De momento tengo el código de JavaScript, donde hago la llamada Ajax de esta forma:
[image: llamada de Ajax a la acción de controlador]

Luego, esta seria la acción a la cual hago el llamado:
[image: Acción del controlador]

Lo que busco hacer en el fondo, es que pasado tantos minutos de inactividad por parte del usuario, se le envié un mensaje consultando si desea mantener su sesión abierta o prefiere cerrarla, en el caso de cerrarla es donde debo hacer la llamada a la acción de logout que tengo creada, la cual viendo el depurador, pasa por ahí, pero no la ejecuta, es como si nunca cerrara sesión.

Gracias a quienes comenten.

Comment: Quita el ajax y pone window.location = "User/Logout" y en el controlador cambia el decorator HttpPost por HttpGet

Comment: [es.so] te da las herramientas para publicar el código _como texto, con formato_. Subir capturas de pantalla de código [es mala idea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: gracias @Yussef con eso me funciono a la perfección.